# How to apply tiny MCE to C#

Tags: c#, javascript, tinymce

Hi guys I just want to apply tinyMCE in my project. I've tried to attached it with my .aspx page but it wont show any changes and the tool box is bot even showing. here is the code i use from [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) just click View Source tab.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Email.aspx.cs" Inherits="Email" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 tinyMCE.init({
     // General options
     mode: "textareas",
     theme: "advanced",
   editor_selector :"mceEditor",
     plugins: "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

     // Theme options
     theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
     theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
     theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
     theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
     theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
     theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
     theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
     theme_advanced_resizing: true,

     // Skin options
     skin: "o2k7",
     skin_variant: "silver",

     // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
     content_css: "styles/style.css",

     // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
     template_external_list_url: "Scripts/template_list.js",
     external_link_list_url: "Scripts/link_list.js",
     external_image_list_url: "Scripts/image_list.js",
     media_external_list_url: "Scripts/media_list.js",

     // Replace values for the template plugin
     template_replace_values: {
         username: "Some User",
         staffid: "991234"
     }
 });

</script>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server"<tr>
    <td width="10%" class="fieldsEmail" align="right" valign="top">Message:&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="90%">
    <textarea id="message" class="mceEditor" cols="20" rows="2" 
            style="width:95%; height:300px;"></textarea>
            </td>
</tr></asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? There is a chance you are not properly applying it.

Comment: Content needs to be running at the server?

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses all of my content are running at server.

Comment: I mean try to delete the `runat="server"` because I guess that will make the server try to run the javascript at the server, I think

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses my codes will not run if the runat="server" is not there.

Comment: But its javascript D: it doesnt need to be run there it needs to be passed to the client

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses If i did that i always get this king of error "Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have already answered my question. The problem is that I didn't attached all the required JavaScript to complete my project. Thanks.